# Where are Android framework classes on the device?

Tags: android, adb, classpath

Where can I find Android framework classes? The file `/system/framework/framework.jar` is empty on my device and no other files in `/system/framework` seem to contain the core library.

To be more specific, I need to retrieve some classes (e.g. `android.app.Activity`) from the device, for instance using ADB, either as a class file or dex.

I know I can find the source code on GitHub, but I cannot find the location on the device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android uses ART now. So all you get for the framework files are `boot-framework.art` and `boot-framework.oat` in the `/system/framework/[arch=arm,arm64,x86_68,etc]/` folder.